# extract string before dash in R

Tags: r, string, extract

I have a column for name, the format is mixed with AAA and AAA-D. I want to extract the name before dash (if it has dash) or keep the non-dashed name. 
the list is

```
Name
W1-D1
Empty
W2-D1
```

what I want to extract are

```
Name
W1
Empty
W2
```

I found several syntaxes like `v1<-gsub("^(.*?)-.*", "\\1",v)`  but this does not work on my list, I got this “c(\"W1"  in  v1  . Did I use this syntax wrong?

Comment: You can use strsplit(Name, "-")[[1]] in mutate (dplyr) to apply for entire column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following regex will do it.

```
sub("(^[^-]+)-.*", "\\1", Name)
#[1] "W1"    "Empty" "W2"
```

**Data.**

```
Name <- scan(what = character(), text ="
W1-D1
Empty
W2-D1
")
```

Comment: I think my main problem is to convert the dataframe correctly. All syntaxes worked now. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

You can as well use stringr

```
library(stringr)

v2<-str_extract(v, "[^-]+")
```